# sqlalchemy claims column has unique requirement when it does not

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following model

models.py

```
class Rules(db.Model):
    name=db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    rule=db.Column(db.Integer, default='0', unique=False)

    def __repr__(self):  # pragma: no cover
        return '<Rules %r>' % (self.name)
```

If I try and store data in it, it claims rule has a unique requirement. I event went so far as to explicitly declare unique=False, but it still claims it has to be unique with the following error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint        failed: rules.rule [SQL: u'INSERT INTO rules (name, rule) VALUES (?, ?)'] [parameters: ('dod_iaa_cyber', '2')]
```

I have ran the following script multiple times to try and migrate it and fix the error to no avail.

db_migrate.py

```
#!flask/bin/python
import imp
from migrate.versioning import api
from app import db
from config import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
from config import SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO
v = api.db_version(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
migration = SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO + ('/versions/%03d_migration.py' % (v+1))
tmp_module = imp.new_module('old_model')
old_model = api.create_model(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
exec old_model in tmp_module.__dict__
script = api.make_update_script_for_model(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI,
                                          SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO,
                                          tmp_module.meta, db.metadata)
open(migration, "wt").write(script)
api.upgrade(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
v = api.db_version(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
print('New migration saved as ' + migration)
print('Current database version: ' + str(v))
```

007_migration.py, all migration from 003-007 are the same as this

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from migrate import *


from migrate.changeset import schema
pre_meta = MetaData()
post_meta = MetaData()

def upgrade(migrate_engine):
    # Upgrade operations go here. Don't create your own engine; bind
    # migrate_engine to your metadata
    pre_meta.bind = migrate_engine
    post_meta.bind = migrate_engine


def downgrade(migrate_engine):
    # Operations to reverse the above upgrade go here.
    pre_meta.bind = migrate_engine
    post_meta.bind = migrate_engine
```

002_migration.py, this one is different than the rest and has rule as a primary key

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from migrate import *


from migrate.changeset import schema
pre_meta = MetaData()
post_meta = MetaData()
rules = Table('rules', post_meta,
    Column('rule', Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False),
    Column('name', String(length=45)),
)


def upgrade(migrate_engine):
    # Upgrade operations go here. Don't create your own engine; bind
    # migrate_engine to your metadata
    pre_meta.bind = migrate_engine
    post_meta.bind = migrate_engine
    post_meta.tables['rules'].create()


def downgrade(migrate_engine):
    # Operations to reverse the above upgrade go here.
    pre_meta.bind = migrate_engine
    post_meta.bind = migrate_engine
    post_meta.tables['rules'].drop()
```

So why are the new migrations not picking up that I changed rule from primary key to just an integer and how can I properly convert it for the future?

Comment: What's in the generated migration files?

Comment: Good call, migration 002 had rule as a primary key and none of them have changed it since to reflect the change that it is not a primary key. Any suggestions on how to force it to migrate properly?

Answer (score 0):

Are your names unique? Having a primary key implies unique for that field.

Comment: Name is supposed to be unique, rule is not supposed to. When I try and add entries to rule it is forcing them to be unique for some unknown reason.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to delete the table Rules in models.py then migrate the datbase thus forcing it to drop. After wards I added Rules back in and migrated again. This time it recognized Rules.rule is not a unique key and migrated properly.

Thanks for the help guys. I'm not sure why it did not catch that I changed rule to a standard integer during the migration, but everything worked out.